# Linear Regression with gradient descent: two questions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand Linear Regression with Gradient Descent and I do not understand this part in my `loss_gradients` function below.

```
import numpy as np

def forward_linear_regression(X, y, weights):

    # dot product weights * inputs
    N = np.dot(X, weights['W'])

    # add bias
    P = N + weights['B']

    # compute loss with MSE
    loss = np.mean(np.power(y - P, 2))

    forward_info = {}
    forward_info['X'] = X
    forward_info['N'] = N
    forward_info['P'] = P
    forward_info['y'] = y

    return loss, forward_info
```

Here is where I'm stuck in my understanding, I have commented out my questions:

```
def loss_gradients(forward_info, weights):

    # to update weights, we need: dLdW = dLdP * dPdN * dNdW
    dLdP = -2 * (forward_info['y'] - forward_info['P'])
    dPdN = np.ones_like(forward_info['N'])
    dNdW = np.transpose(forward_info['X'], (1, 0))

    dLdW = np.dot(dNdW, dLdP * dPdN)
    # why do we mix matrix multiplication and dot product like this?
    # Why not dLdP * dPdN * dNdW instead?

    # to update biases, we need: dLdB = dLdP * dPdB
    dPdB = np.ones_like(forward_info[weights['B']])
    dLdB = np.sum(dLdP * dPdB, axis=0)
    # why do we sum those values along axis 0?
    # why not just dLdP * dPdB ?
```

Comment: Where did you get the loss_gradient function? It sounds like you didn't write it yourself. Is it from a textbook?

Comment: Yes, it's from a book 'Deep Learning from scratch'  by S. Weidman

Comment: Please include such info in your post - it is a matter of proper attribution, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this code is expecting a 'batch' of data. What I mean by that is, it's expecting that when you do `forward_info` and `loss_gradients`, you're actually passing a bunch of (X, y) pairs together. Let's say you pass B such pairs. The first dimension of all of your forward info stuff will have size B.

Now, the answers to both of your questions are the same: essentially, these lines compute the gradients (using the formulas you predicted) *for each of the B terms*, and then sum up all of the gradients so you get one gradient update. I encourage you to work out the logic behind the dot product yourself, because this is a very common pattern in ML, but it's a little tricky to get the hang of at first.

Comment: Oh! I understand the logic behind summing up the gradients of the biases now. Can you help working out the logic behind the dot product for weights updates? This stuff is hard. Now I'm wondering why we don't just do np.sum(dLdP * dPdN * dNdW) as well for the weights gradients, following the same logic that we use for bias gradients.

Comment: edit: actually wouldn't np.sum(dLdP * dPdN * dNdW) just work ?

Comment: another question: why train with a batch a data? and not just one sample at a time? does it helps with convergence in some way? my current understanding is that it is the exact same as doing one sample at a time.

Comment: With regard to why you train batches, there are a few reasons. One, similar to what you suggested, is to improve stability in training. The gradients you compute are actually estimators for an expected gradient, so gradients based on one sample can be very noisy. Another reason to use batches is that it's actually more efficient, especially when you're using python and numpy: firstly, numpy is written in C (or some other fast compiled language, I don't remember tbh), so in general the more you pass to numpy in one go, the better.

Comment: With regard to the dot product: check the shapes of the tensors in the equations you propose. I don't think the shapes match up well in your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I looked more into the shapes of the values in my code and it all makes sense now.